# Java calling methods from restricted layer

Tags: java, security, reflection, service, layer

I'm not even sure if this is doable but I want to ask the community for their general opinion.

I have to solve a following problem:

My Project has 2 Layers, a Core layer and a Business layer.
This Core layer is providing the Business layer. At this moment Business classes can import Core classes and do whatever they want. Core classes can only import core classes and use their methods, the access to Business classes and their respective methods is forbidden.

I want to add a specific feature:
I don't want to give Core any normal access to the Business layer, but I want to create something like an interface or anything similar (I don't know how to express myself here cause I have no idea if its possible), that provides the Core classes some specific methods from Business classes to use.

Can anyone help me out, or at least give me some guidelines what to read, or where to search.

Thanks in advance for any support.

Edit:
I use Spring Framework with Seam and JBoss

Comment: Move the _specific methods_ from business to core layer. Or consider using a common module.

Comment: By the look of your definition of Core and Business layers, I'd say keep the Core classes core, i.e. kind of a framework. Only the Business layer should depend on anything that's generic (which the Core is supposed to provide). So, if you have something that the Business layer provides and wants to be used by Core, it sounds logical to decouple that functionality and add it to Core.

Answer (score 1):

What you are probably facing is the design of module dependency and circular dependency.  In short, the Business methods that Core needs may have to be re-factored into a 'utils' module or a 'Business-Core' module that is then accessible by both.  I am only guessing here.

In addition to automating builds, a build tool like Maven also encourages such modularization and dependency. It is not unusual for a project that started off as one module to be split into 3-4 modules by the time it is done.

Comment: Ok. What would you suggest if I don't want Core to have access to whole Business layer, but only a very specific part of business, I'm using maven.

Comment: If you do not want a third module: I would add a generic interface to Core that is implemented by something in Business.  You can then look up the implementation through the Java ServiceLoader or your own factory and pass the interface back to core.  There would still be a circular dependency but there would be no imports of Business classes into Core.  The only way to avoid circular dependency would be to create a third module (T) so that C depends on T and B depends on T.  Such modules are usually called 'api' or 'spi' and are almost entirely composed of interfaces, factories, and constants.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by using AspectJ. You can write rules in AspectJ-syntax which will give build-time-errors if not enforced. See the article [Archtectual Enforcement with Aid of AspectJ](http://www.jayway.com/2010/03/28/architectural-enforcement-with-aid-of-aspectj) for an example.