# Java dependency triggers

Tags: java, spring, security, dependencies, seam

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java calling methods from restricted layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13508684/java-calling-methods-from-restricted-layer)

Lest say i have this:

```
package org.service;
import org.core;

public class Service()
{
    public void init()
    {
        Core core = new Core();
        core.callbackFunction();
    }
    public void support()
    {
         ...
    }
}

package org.core
public class Core()
{
    public void callbackFunction()
    {
        ...
    }

    public void useSerivice()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

- Service imports Core
- Core must not import Service

when init() method from Service is called it calls core.callbackFunction() method.

Is it possible to provide as an argument for callbackFunction a reference to a Service method that Core can then trigger when he is executing his support() method.

For instance:

when support() method from Core is called it triggers calling methods from Service. The list of methods that are called are provided from Service while calling Core's callbackFunction() method.

I hope my question is understandable.

Im using Spring and Seam Fw.

Comment: This is the same question as this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13508684/java-calling-methods-from-restricted-layer/13508776

Comment: @akberc It appears to be related, but I wouldn't say it was the same question.

Answer (score 1):

How about the design below? Your implementation of `bar()` in the `Service` class could call other methods as needed.

```
public interface Foo {
    void bar();
}

public class Service implements Foo {
    public void init() {
        Core core = new Core();
        core.callbackFunction(this);
    }

    @Override
    public bar() {
        // impl here
    }
}

public class Core() {

    private Foo foo;

    public void callbackFunction(Foo foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }

    public void useService() {
        if (foo != null) {
            foo.bar();
        } else {
            // Uh-oh.
        }
    }
}
```

I would also strongly recommend the `Foo` instance is passed in the constructor of the `Core` class to avoid the need for the `if (foo != null)` test.

Comment: It's not very clear from the original post when Core.useService() would be called, but this looks like a decent generic solution.  I would change one thing: Service implementing Foo is a broken encapsulation that you can fix by using an instance of an inner class inside Service instead of "this" (e.g. anonymous but doesn't have to be).

Comment: @DaveSyer How does it break encapsulation? As far as `Core` is concerned, it just receives a `Foo` regardless of whether its an inner class or the entirety of `Service`. Or have I misunderstood encapsulation (quite possible!)?

Comment: It's not a big deal.  Consider the business clients of Service - do they really need Service to be a Foo (the only reason it is in your code is to satisfy a low level internal dependency)?